# Firebase v3.2 iOS - how to stop the logs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

The new [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) started logging to console (`print`), as in:

```
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
```

How do I stop it?

I don't mean removing analytics, I mean stop the `print`'s.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop INFO, ERROR and WARNING logs.